# Finding all times from an individual event

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Apologies Im quite new to using SQL.

I have data that looks like this

| ID | Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/01/01 00:23 | 2023/01/01 00:26 | 2023/01/01 00:29 |
| 1 | 2023/01/01 00:23 | 2023/01/01 00:27 | 2023/01/01 00:28 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 04:51 | 2023/01/01 04:55 | 2023/01/01 05:10 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 12:31 | 2023/01/01 12:33 | 2023/01/01 12:59 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 12:31 | 2023/01/01 12:43 | 2023/01/01 12:51 |
| 3 | 2023/01/01 12:36 | 2023/01/01 12:37 | 2023/01/01 12:39 |

I'm trying to get all times that relate to the second time in Time 3 for each ID.

| ID | Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 -- | 2023/01/01 00:23 ----- | 2023/01/01 00:26----- | 2023/01/01 00:29---- |
| 1 | 2023/01/01 00:23 | 2023/01/01 00:27 | 2023/01/01 00:28 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 04:51 | 2023/01/01 04:55 | 2023/01/01 05:10 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 12:31 | 2023/01/01 12:33 | 2023/01/01 12:59 |
| 2 -- | 2023/01/01 12:31 ----- | 2023/01/01 12:43----- | 2023/01/01 12:51 ----- |
| 3 | 2023/01/01 12:36 | 2023/01/01 12:37 | 2023/01/01 12:39 |

I have highlighted the two that I'm trying to get.

What I've done so far takes the 2nd time from each TimeStamp but that often return different times.

| ID | TimeStamp 1 | TimeStamp 2 | TimeStamp 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/01/01 00:23 | 2023/01/01 00:26 | 2023/01/01 00:29 ----- |
| 1 | 2023/01/01 00:23 ----- | 2023/01/01 00:27 ---- | 2023/01/01 00:28 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 04:51 | 2023/01/01 04:55 | 2023/01/01 05:10 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 12:31 ----- | 2023/01/01 12:33 ---- | 2023/01/01 12:59 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 12:33 | 2023/01/01 12:43 | 2023/01/01 12:51 ----- |
| 3 | 2023/01/01 12:36 | 2023/01/01 12:37 | 2023/01/01 15:39 |

I don't have a unique number for each event in the ID

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return one row for each id, the row having the second Timestamp3?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want rows with the second last `time3` for each id. If so, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by timestamp3) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 2
```